# How do I remove all comments from docx file using Apache POI or Docx4j?

Tags: apache-poi, docx4j

I'm not able to remove all the comments present in docx file using Apache POI . 
Is there any other way of removing the comments using docx4j api ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Basically it is 2 steps.

Step 1: find the various comment tags in the main document part and delete them.

Step 2: delete the comments part.

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/CommentsDeleter.java does step 1.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link . It really helped !